# Combining Jquery's Colorbox plugin with and Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

In searching the net to do java script popup messages and displays I found [jQuery and a the colorbox pluggin](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-window.phtml)  a fantastic tool set.  Also months ago on another
project I found discussions about the Ajax technique to dynamically re-write portions of the displayed webpage.  I want to combine the two.  I am trying to use one click to bring up a colorbox popup and simultaneously re-write the underlying page.
Here are the two java script functions...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/colorbox(1).css" />         
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".small").colorbox({inline:true, width:"45%", opacity:0.4});
            $(".medium").colorbox({inline:true, width:"53%", opacity:0.4});
            $(".large").colorbox({inline:true, width:"65%", opacity:0.4});
            });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cmpltadd(tab)
{
  if (tab=="")
  {
      document.getElementById("repostarea").innerHTML="";
      return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
       document.getElementById("repostarea").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("POST","../includes/cmpltadd.php?q="+tab,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

And then in the body I have a mapped image with colorbox 'class' links to  generate popups of inline html

```
<div id="repostarea">
 <img src="../images/ansitabwnwsi.jpg"  Title="Add New Form Security Image tab with new image"  usemap="#sitabwimg" /><br>
            <map name="sitabwimg" id="sitabwimg"> 
          <area shape="rect" coords="177,59,282,164" class="medium" href="#repimg" title="Replace Image" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="26,106,159,130" class="medium" href="#imgnam" title="edit image name" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="108,141,129,162" class="medium" href="#dltbut" title="Delete current Image entry" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="135,141,158,162" class=large" href="#sitab1si" title="Add image" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="22,189,168,212" class="medium" href="#sidat" title="Creation date" />
          <area shape="default"  nohreh="nohref" Title="Browse for the security image" /> </map> <br>
</div>
```

Here is one of the inline popups....  Notice that one of the above hrefs and the div id below match

```
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='sitab1si' style='padding:10px; background:#6C848B;'>
<p><strong> <h3>Security image tab with new image</h3>
   Now that the image is selected the dates are filled-in automatically and you are asked to provide an image name.  Just     like with 
            the entry name this is important and if not entered immediately may be requested several times. 
            <img src="../images/ansitabwnwsi.jpg"  Title="Add New Form Security Image tab with new image"  usemap="#sitabwimg" /><br>
            <map name="sitabwimg" id="sitabwimg"> 
          <area shape="rect" coords="177,59,282,164" class="medium" href="#repimg" title="Replace Image" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="26,106,159,130" class="medium" href="#imgnam" title="edit image name" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="108,141,129,162" class="medium" href="#dltbut" title="Delete current Image entry" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="135,141,158,162" class="medium" href="#addbut" title="Add image" />
          <area shape="rect" coords="22,189,168,212" class="medium" href="#sidat" title="Creation date" />
          <area shape="default"  nohreh="nohref" Title="Browse for the security image" /> </map> <br>
          <ol>On this tab you can now </li>
          <li>change/replace the image by double clicking on it</li>
          <li>edit the description or name</li>
          <li>delete the image with it name by pressing the Delete button</li>
          <li>add a new image by pressing the Add button.</li> </ol>
          <a href="#addsibws" class="large" title="Browse for the security image"> Return</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cmpltadd('si');"> Done </a>
          </strong></p>
          </div>
       </div>
```

OK, so the first image map has a map area that links to the popup; in the popup the very last link is "Done."  When the user clicks on it, it initiates the rewrite of a portion ("repostarea" div) of the page (underneath the javapopup).  It all works fine.  But what I want to happen is when the user clicks on the map area that brings up the popup I want to also simultaneously call the cmpltadd('si') function (calls a simple php script to echo html code).  Can I get two results from one action is the question I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

First, jQuery has a very concise and reliable ajax method allowing `cmpltadd()` to be written like this :

```
function cmpltadd(tab) {
    if (tab == "") {
        $("#repostarea").html("");
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "../includes/cmpltadd.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {q: tab},
        success: function(html) {
            $("#repostarea").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

To open the popups, you presumably already have something like this :

```
$("#sitabwimg").on('click', 'area', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tabID = this.href;
    $(tabID).colorBox(...);
});
```

To get the two actions from the one click, you need to add a call to `cmpltadd()`.

```
$("#sitabwimg").on('click', 'area', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var tabID = this.href;
    $(tabID).colorbox(...);
    cmpltadd(tabID);
});
```

You should now not need to call `cmpltadd()` when the popups are closed but if you still  need for something to happen, then you can specify an `onClosed` callback function in the `.colorbox()` options, for example :

```
$(selector).colorbox({
    //other options here
onClosed: function() { 
        //do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will experiment with that tomorrow